# Unable To Install Ubuntu 13.04 on Alienware 17

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi, alienware

So I go to boot Ubuntu from USB and I get to the Ubuntu boot screen, but when I go to install it I get a black screen but I hear the sounds. My computer uses UEFI with secure boot; when I turn it off it does not fix the issue, same with legacy boot. It should also be noted that legacy boot makes it so it doesn't recognize Win 8 (already installed). Can anyone assist with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

13.04 will be outdated in about 10 days from today, download the latest version ([Ubuntu 13.10](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc)) and when you disable the UEFI boot and activate legacy boot make sure you you really are loading the USB via legacy and not EFI mode, if you are getting a black screen to select the option to install ubuntu you are doing it through EFI and it is giving you problems, if you do it through legacy you will see a purple GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with same pc. My problem was the distribution. I put 13.10 on a usb and booted to that (hit F12 at startup). Installed to a previously set up partition on the second hdd. Make sure fast boot is off and secure boot is off. You can turn these on later. 13.10 should have all the drivers you need.